# How would I get Python to create a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I'm trying to do is get Python to create a batch file for me which I can put what the text is that I need in the file just by coding it. What I began to do is create a text file with the open() method, I then added the text I need in the batch file using write() but now I want it to be a .bat file with the text in that text file, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new file with the `open()` function, you state its file name. Just give it a name with the `.bat` extension, and it has become a `.bat` file. Of course, this assumes the program is running in the Windows environment, where the concept of a `.bat` file makes sense.

Then just write the appropriate text into the file, then close the file properly with the `close()` function, or even better using the end of the `with` construct. You may need to flush the file system to ensure that all text was written to the file.

If you need more details, add more details to your question about your specific difficulty.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! :)

Comment: Sorry about that Rory I'm currently new to stack overflow, I have now accepted it as an answer but It won't let me up vote as I still have not gained enough reputation.

Comment: @JadA: No problem. I should have mentioned that in my comment.